How to write a piece of source code that can be executed as both C and Python, outputting 'Hello World'
I'm trying to write a piece of source code that is compatible with both C and Python compilers/interpreters, outputting "Hello World" in stdout.
Here are two of my tries:
#if __STDC__

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}

#else

print("Hello, World!")
exit()

#endif

""""
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
"""""

print("Hello World!")

However, both don't work, leading to compile error.

C and Python are very different languages. Why would you want to do something like that anyway ?

This seems like a question more for the code golf stack exchange if anything

@wohlstad Because I saw this challenge in an ARG game, and I want to figure it out.

I don't think that it's possible to write such program. Even if yes, you would need to use some kind of hack, which isn't scalable at all.

@Verpous You're right, but I dind't know "code golf stack exchange" before. Should I move this question to that place?

@ViliamHolly I'm not looking for a scalable solution, but for just a "Hello World". I think, just like what you said, I'm looking for "some kind of hack”.

@ViliamHolly It is possible. It's not particularly useful, other than as an exercise in developing one's skills - but it is definitely possible.

@NoNormalCreeper: I don't think the question's a good fit for Code Golf - that's more about challenges on who can write the shortest program to achieve a specific goal. Might be worth searching there to see if there's already a related challenge there, though, as the answers might be relevant.

This would be considered too trivial if you post it on PPCG. Check their polyglot tag to get some ideas.

@wohlstad: It is called a polyglot and you do it because it requires thinking about language details you may have neglected or about using them in novel ways, which trains your brain to remember more about the language and to think creatively, and because it is fun. Doing mental exercises with no apparent productive output is like doing physical exercises that have no apparent productive output like lifting weights and putting them back down again. The latter trains your muscles to be stronger. The former trains your brain to be stronger.

@EricPostpischil I can definately understand mental excercising. I was not familiar with the term polyglot, and I was curious what's the need to combine 2 such different languages into one source file. Now I understand.

@psmears As a medium-rep user there I can ensure you what PPCG (now called CGCC?) is about is more than just code golfing.

@WeijunZhou: Yeah that's why I sad "more about" rather than "only about" - was really just trying to say that (like you) I don't think this question (as it stands) would go down well there, not trying to do the site down!

You're along the right lines, so here are some clues:

You can hide things from C using #if or #ifdef:
 #ifdef THIS_IS_PYTHON
 ... python code ignored by C compiler ...
 #endif


You can (effectively) hide things from Python by enclosing them in """ (three quotes):
 """
 ... C code ignored by Python interpreter ...
 """


The C compiler will choke on the """... but you know a way to hide things from the C compiler, right?



That works! Thanks a lot for your hint!
#ifdef THIS_IS_PYTHON
print("Hello World!")
#endif

#ifdef THIS_IS_PYTHON
"""
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("Hello World!");
    return 0;
}

#ifdef THIS_IS_PYTHON
"""
#endif


Now I'm thinking about writing a Quine program according to this, making both runaable in Python and C, could you give some hints?

@NoNormalCreeper: No worries - glad you managed to figure it out :)

@NoNormalCreeper: Now that's trickier, but I think it should be possible - good luck :)

@NoNormalCreeper: I don't have any hints for that specifically - I'd suggest searching around for hints on writing quines / polyglot programs; as has been suggested the Code Golf stack exchange has probably got some relevant challenges (with answers).

OK, thanks a lot for your help!
